# How to suppress Matlab 2010 Java error in MacOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, matlab, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I run MATLAB 2010 on MacOS High Sierra. I get the Java error below in the Command Window every time I run MATLAB or try to do anything in the Command Window. My codes run OK, but I cannot utilize the Command Window (>>) because of this error. My research indicates that it is a compatibility issue that hasn't been resolved yet. Can I -at least- suppress the error (prevent it from appearing) and how?

Here is the error(s) I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Non-Java exception raised, not handled! (Original problem: Deprecated in 10_12... DO NOT EVER USE CGSEventRecord directly. Bad things, man.... bad things.)
at apple.awt.ComponentModel._handleEvent(Native Method)
at apple.awt.ComponentModel.handleEvent(ComponentModel.java:273)
at apple.awt.CWindow.handleEvent(CWindow.java:545)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:753)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1000)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:865)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:686)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4648)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: I just noticed that the end of the first line of the error says "Bad things, man.... bad things.". This is not a joke. It's part of the error I get.

Comment: If you read what is stated directly before that it says **"DO NOT EVER USE CGSEventRecord directly"** — why not fix the error instead of trying to suppress it?

Comment: @l'L'l I didn't notice that, and I don't even know what it is. Thanks for bringing my attention to it. I will see if that I can do something and will update here.

Comment: @l'L'l Just checked MATLAB website. It is really unfixable. El Capitan was the last version in which you could reliable configure preferences multiple Java versions.